# How to keep a development environment clean?

Tags: linux, debian, administration, development

1. Working as a hobby developer on Debian/Jessie64

   2. mostly C++ but also assembly, python, java, c, c#
   3. like compiling programs on my own like
   4. looking into other's source

it results into many packages(libraries/tools) installed and so making the system slow (look for a library in a folder with a few hundred libs is faster than a thousands of - same for bin)

how do you keep your machine clean?
remembering packages and uninstalling (complicated, time consuming)?
apt-get autoremove? also removes additional packages not "needed" but useful

using virtualbox for a dev-machine?

is it possible, to tell gcc to look for headers on a different machine and the same for ld for the libraries to link?

*EDIT*

with "slower" I mean that programs (browsers, IDE) start a bit slower (not measured)

I already use vagrant for working with LAMP stacks or other things I definitely don't want on my machine

Didn't think about chrooting for a dev-env, definitely have to try this.

Comment: Use [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) with VirtualBox.  Single command to create a clean environment.  Single command to destroy it so you can start again fresh.

Comment: Unless you install many thousands of libraries in `/usr/lib`, you'd not be able to notice any slowdown.

Answer (score 2):

One possible idea is to create a chroot environment, in which you chroot to, install whatever you need to, do your dev work, and then exit when your done. This should leave everything outside of the chroot environment unaffected.